# Device not finding a CD/DVD Drive

Tags: 14.04, drivers, dvd, cd-drive

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 from a disk I downloaded and burned on this laptop whilst it was running Win8.1. Laptop is an HP Pavilion g6.

Clearly the CD/DVD drive works, as the instillation completed, but now Ubuntu does not read the drive.
I put cds in, and get the standard mechanical sounds, but nothing on screen.
media/cdrom is present and correct, but without any contents (regardless of having a disk in the drive or not).
I ran `sudo lshw -class disk` and received:

```
*-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST1000LM024 HN-M
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 0002
       serial: S2SWJ9ACA11106
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=a1e00938-1015-4bb4-9a4b-a95f404e111d sectorsize=4096
```

Not sure what command I should run in order that I can access cds and dvds on this drive.

Any sugestions?

Comment: is it a blank disk? run the command `lsblk` and you should see sr0 listed. Is it listed?

Comment: It wasn't a blank disk. The command gave me: NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0   244M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0 930.8G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0 923.3G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   7.5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]

Comment: OK, so I Installed package ubuntu-restricted-extras:     sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras . Then ran:    sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh . All seems to be working now.  Thanks for looking anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I Installed package ubuntu-restricted-extras:`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Then ran: `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

All seems to be working now.

Thanks for looking anyhow

Comment: now that it has been two days, you should be able to  accept your own answer as the solution by clicking the icon to the left